# Apache wont listen on other ports except on port 80

Tags: linux, laravel, amazon-web-services, apache, ubuntu

I have a amazon ec2 instance using Ubuntu server 18.04, I configured the config files and added them to sites-enable by doing `sudo a2ensite`. Port 88 is not accesible only port 80. Can someone tell me what the problem of this? Should I inclue the IP? Do i need to apply elastic IP on it in order to work? since i am using the public IP on this one.

PS: my account on amazon is free tier subscription meaning, i can only make one instance. I am using ubuntu 18.04. Im deploying laravel application

ports.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 88
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Port 80 (main project) 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/capstoneproject/public


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


<Directory "/var/www/html/capstoneproject/public">
 AllowOverride all
 Require all granted
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Port 88

```
<VirtualHost *:88>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Inventory/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory "/var/www/html/Inventory/public">
 AllowOverride all
 Require all granted
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Already tried restarting apache but wont work.

UPDATE:
i tried running `netstat -anp | grep apache2` and i got

```
tcp6       0      0 :::88                   :::*                    LISTEN      11685/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11685/apache2
```

Still wont work. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify the Security Group in EC2.

From the EC2 dashboard, go to the "Instances" tab and click on your instance. Then go to the Security Group section and click on "view inbound rules". You'll be able to see the ports open. You'll need to change the Security Group rules your instance is connected to. Click on the security group name in the panel where you saw "view inbound rules". It should take you to another page where you will be able to edit all the firewall rules.

Comment: yah. thanks for it bro. just an AWS related error. need to add port 88 in security groups